# IP KVMs / remote access to linux x11 session with no window-manager

Tags: linux, desktop, ip, kvm

can somebody recommend me good affordable IP KVM?  Like Adder.  Or some articles evaluating such KVMs?

My project:

Provide remote support to Linux (Fedora) based software that runs on X, but without any window-manager.  I know that there is Gnome vino, but it is buggy and it does not meet my needs for other reasons.  I would prefer a hardware solution, although I am still willing to look into sw solutions too.

I have a similar project, where I need to support a DOS-based medical device.

In many cases it would be enough for the remote supporter to see the screen, they could guide the on-site person to type/mouse.

TIA,
Radim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set up a Xserver on a media center without local mouse/keyboard/monitor, so I can control it remotely.

The trick is to use the X Virtual Framebuffer and the X11vnc server.

Something like this:

```
/usr/bin/xinit /home/dummyuser/.xinitrc -- /usr/bin/Xvfb :20 -screen 0 1200x720x16 +kb -cc 4 -nolisten tcp -deferglyphs

/usr/bin/x11vnc -display :20
```

and with **/home/dummyuser/.xinitrc**:

```
cd /home/dummyuser
umask 002
fluxbox & wmpid=$!
# here your startup programs
wait $wmpid
```

It uses fluxbox which is lightweight window manager. You can use openbox as well. You may remove the window manager if it is not necessary.

Then, you can connect to it with any vnc client, and open terminals, firefox, etc.

Comment: After further consideration I am now only looking for HARDWARE solutions.  So far I looked at Adder IPEPS, Raritan Dominion, Lantronix Spider.  Is there anybody with hands-pn experience with one or more of these?  TIA, Radim